# Unicorn hot restart with ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 3.2.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, ubuntu-12.04, unicorn

I am running e-commerce ruby on rails application using Unicorn app server. The ruby version is 2.0.0 and the rails version is 3.2.14. I am running Nginx as web server. When ever I push the code to the server, I need to restart the unicorn app server, which is causing a blup/bleep in the website, I googled around for the solution but nothing seem to be working. I was using passenger before which was fine.

Is there any way to avoid blup's during restarting hence maintain zero downtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send USR2 to the unicorn master, it will cause the unicorn workers to restart, and should cause a zero downtime restart.  Send the USR2 signal with:

```
kill -s USR2 process-id-of-master-process
```

Replace the process-id-of-master-process with the numeric process id of the unicorn master (find it with ps agx | grep unicorn, or look in the pids folder for unicorn.pid

Note that if unicorn is running under Bundler, you will still need to do a cold restart whenever you change the Gemfile, in order for the new Gemfile to be picked up.

Comment: I am using "bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production" this command to start the unicorn.

Comment: Send the USR2 signal to your master process, & the workers will pick up any new application code EXCEPT the Gemfile.  So, if you aren't changing the Gemfile, USR2 is your ticket to a zero downtime restart.  No need to re-run bundle exec if you use USR2, and if your new app fails to restart, the old one will still run.  If you DO change Gemfile, send the QUIT signal to the master, then run your bundle exec unicorn ... command to start up a new unicorn master, but that won't be a zero downtime restart, and if there is a problem with your app and it doesn't start, you are down until its fixed.

Comment: kill -s USR2 process-id-of-master-process is working fine for me. After using the above command it creates 2 more new processes, which serves the latest code and but the old child process still exists and it also serves the old code. Should I kill the old child process?/What is the solution ?

Comment: I haven't seen where USR2 both started new child processes and left the old ones running.  If the new child processes have a problem loading the new code, they exit and leave the old children running. In the usual case, the new children start up, and then signal old children to exit.  You should not have to manually kill the old children.  Check both your Rails production.log and unicorn log (in the same directory as production.log) to make sure that there are no errors encountered by the new children stating.  If you do need to kill the old children, do it by sending QUIT to the old master.

Comment: the common pattern is to wait until new code is loaded but then kill -s QUIT the old master: sig USR2 && sleep 15 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT